# Identity server 4 userinfo endpoint returns status code 204 (No content)

Tags: identityserver4

I am having a very hard time figuring out why my userinfo endpoint is returning a status code of 204 (No Content). All the other endpoints are returning as expected except for the userinfo endpoint.

[image]
[image]

Comment: As always - you need to turn on logging to see what's going on...

Comment: Your OPTIONS call seems to be returning a 204, but what about your GET? And as leastprivilege says, turn on logging and that will probably give you more information.

Comment: I havent gotten by for the most part without having to turn on logging so I am struggling to find where to turn on the logging. If you can indulge me I will appreciate that very much

Comment: Ok, I did get logging working I however did not get much to get started with. This is what I got "2017-06-12 20:28:17.670 +01:00 [Verbose] Invoking result: "IdentityServer4.Endpoints.Results.JsonWebKeysResult"
2017-06-12 20:28:17.683 +01:00 [Information] Request finished in 26.4366ms 200 application/json
2017-06-12 20:28:17.831 +01:00 [Information] Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:44361/connect/userinfo  
2017-06-12 20:28:17.832 +01:00 [Information] Request finished in 1.3589ms 204 " I was expecting "https" and not "http" in the url. Could this be a contributory factor?